# PHP - Validating date is in format d/m/Y

Tags: php, date

I am importing dates from a CSV that requires the format to be d/m/Y eg: 20/4/1999.

How can I check that users entering it correctly and not m/d/Y eg: 4/20/1999.

I tried using the following but it returns false for both cases

```
function validateDateFormats(string $date, string $format='d/m/Y')
    {
        $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
        return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
    }

var_dump(validateDateFormats('20/4/1999'));
var_dump(validateDateFormats('4/20/1999'));
```

The above function returns true for '04/20/1999'. But is there a way to have it return true for '4/20/1999' as well?

These dates should return true: 20/4/1999, 20/04/1999

These dates should return false: 04/20/1999, 4/20/1999

Thanks

Comment: Yeah that is ok. If the user enters 5/5/2000, I'll just take it as May 5. My main concern is checking that the month is not greater than 12. My last resort is checking via explode, but I'd prefer something more elegant.

Comment: Sorry I previously got confused about `d/m/y` and `m/d/y`. I'm glad my answer helped you.

Comment: You cannot find out if format is `d/m/Y` or `m/d/Y`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  function validateDateFormats(string $date, string $format='d/m/Y')
>     {
>     $d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
>     return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
>     }
>
> var_dump(validateDateFormats('20/4/1999'));
> var_dump(validateDateFormats('4/20/1999'));
> ```
>
> The above function returns true for '04/20/1999'. But is there a way to have it return true for '4/20/1999' as well?

From [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php):

> m     Numeric representation of a month, with leading zeros   01 through 12
>   n     Numeric representation of a month, without leading zeros    1 through 12

Therefore what about  `var_dump(validateDateFormats('4/20/1999','n/d/Y'));`?

Look at the function and see the second argument gives you the date format required to return true, so all you need to do is to apply the `format` string in your function to change `m` to `n`.

Thus:

```
$date = "4/20/2019";
if( validateDateFormats($date, 'm/d/Y')
    ||  validateDateFormats($date, 'n/d/Y') ){
    print "This date is valid."; 
}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion. But '4/20/1999' will still come out as false.  '04/20/1999' will return true.

Comment: I understand why it's not working, since the function is expecting the date string in a specific format. I'm wondering what's the best way to validate it using something else.